# Where can I watch/stream English subbed Yu-Gi-Oh! Duel Monsters?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I've searched Google about the series but no results were found.

Where can I legally watch/stream English subbed *Yu-Gi-Oh! Duel Monsters*?

Comment: Have a look at [the list on our meta site](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/922/how-can-i-tell-if-a-site-is-legal/923#923).

Answer (score 3):

- [Hulu (Dub & Sub)](https://www.hulu.com/yu-gi-oh)
- [Crunchyroll (Sub only)](http://www.crunchyroll.com/yu-gi-oh)
- [Yahoo! View (Dub only)](https://view.yahoo.com/show/yu-gi-oh)
- [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/481/Yu%E2%98%86Gi%E2%98%86Oh_Duel_Monsters)